# What does "[w for w in word_tokens if..." mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have a general question about the syntax used in Python. I am very new to programming so this might seem like a noob question, but I'm using pythons nltk, and in that there is a command which appears as follows...

```
word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_sent)

filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]

filtered_sentence = []

for w in word_tokens:
if w not in stop_words:
    filtered_sentence.append(w)
```

Is anyone able to explain the logic behind the "w for w in word_tokens"?
I have seen this in several forms, so can anyone break down what is happening here in the "X for X in X"?

Would just like some clarity on the concept used here, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a list comprehension. You should google this as it can be a pretty confusing subject, which is hard to explain in a single answer. That's a 'representative' of the _functional_ programming paradigm.

Answer (score 6):

```
filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
```

is equivalent to:

```
filtered_sentence = []
for w in word_tokens:
    if not w in stopwords:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
```